# Expo Push Token Registration Fails

Tags: expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, eas

I try to get push notifications working on a standalone build for Android. They work for iOS and they work for any device when using Expo Go. This indicates, my configuration is wrong.

I followed the following guide several times: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#android

I'll describe in detail what I do. First, I'll delete existing projects etc. and then set it up from scratch.

1. I go to expo.dev -> Project -> Credentials -> Remove the application identifies for android.
2. I go to https://console.firebase.google.com/ and delete my project (none are left)
3. https://console.firebase.google.com/ -> Create Project
4. Select a name -> next -> Choose Default Account for Firebase -> Project being created
5. Project Settings -> Add Android App -> use package name as defined in my app.json (see below) -> Register app
6. Download google-services.json and replace existing one -> Next -> Next -> Next
7. As you can see, the `app.json` points to the file correctly.
8. Check the API Key: It's the same online and in the services files.
9. It seems to me, that the google-services.json file is good. See below.
10. Run `eas credentials` -> Choose Android -> Choose my test profile -> Set up a new keystore -> Generate Keystore
11. Go to the FCM console and in my project, go to "Cloud Messaging".
12. I enable the legacy API.
13. Copy the server key token.
14. Go to expo.dev to project settings -> Credentials -> add the server key token to the app identifier as a Google Cloud Messaging Token.
15. Done

Now if I build with eas: `eas build --profile test --platform android` and I start my app, no token is being fetched.

I can't see what is wrong.

`App.json`

```json
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "Spark",
        "slug": "Spark",
        "version": "1.0.7",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": [
            "**/*"
        ],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "android": {
            "package": "com.spark_new.spark_ui_test_new",
            "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            },
            "permissions": [
                "CAMERA",
                "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
                "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
            ]
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
        },
        "plugins": [
            [
                "expo-image-picker",
                {
                    "photosPermission": "Access to photos is required to choose a profile & project pictures."
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

`google-services.json`

```json
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "887403387211",
    "project_id": "spark-163cc",
    "storage_bucket": "spark-163cc.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:887403387211:android:642c447d9d7dbb9ae8f0ce",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.spark_new.spark_ui_test_new"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "..."
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```